# Getting access to functions from subdirectories

Tags: go

I'm writing small app following http://golang.org/doc/code.html

My directory tree looks like

```
-blog
  -bin
  -pkg
  -src
    -github.com
      -packages_that_i_imported
    -myblog
      -config
        routes.go
      server.go
```

my `server.go` file contains following code

```
package main

import "..." //ommited imports


func main(){
    r:= mux.InitRoutes()  //function from imported package
    Register_routes(r)  //function from routes.go
}
```

And my routes.go

```
package main

func Register_routes(r *Router){
  r.addRoute("test", "test", "test)
}
```

But after I do `go run server.go`
I'm getting following error

```
$ go run server.go 
# command-line-arguments
./server.go:10: undefined: Register_routes
```

GOPATH variable points to my `/blog` folder

What am I missing? Why go doesn't it see files in subdirectories?

P.S. config/routes.go is part of server.go package

P.P.S I have moved routes.go to the same folder as server.go, but the error is still present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a function defined in another package, first you have to import it:

```
import "myblog/config"
```

And after that you have to refer to it by the package name:

```
config.Register_routes(r)
```

Also the package name should reflect the folder name in which it is defined. In your routes.go the package should be `config`. Package `main` is special, the `main` package will be compiled into an executable binary (it is the entry point of the program). See [Program Execution](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) in the language specification.

From the page you linked: [Package names](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackageNames):

> Go's convention is that the package name is the last element of the import path: the package imported as `"crypto/rot13"` should be named `rot13`.
>
> Executable commands must always use package `main`.
>
> There is no requirement that package names be unique across all packages linked into a single binary, only that the import paths (their full file names) be unique.

Check out the blog post [Package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) for a detailed guideline.

Note that different files of the same package have to be put into the same folder. And different files of the same package can use everything from the package without importing it and without using the package name (doesn't matter in which file it is defined). This is also true for unexported identifiers. From another package you can only access exported identifiers (their name must start with a capital letter).

Also the go naming convention is to used mixed caps rather than underscores to write multiword names, see [Effective Go / MixedCaps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps). So the function should be named `RegisterRoutes` but this is not a requirement.

Comment: Isnt this is same package? Both have package 'main' at top, and lies within subdirectory

Comment: @Avdept `main` packages from multiple folders are not compiled into the same package. Your `routes.go` should be declared in package `config` based on the folder it is in.

Comment: does that means, if i want to have `autoimport` files, they must be in same directory as file with `main` func?

Comment: @Avdept Different files of the same package have to be put into the same folder. And different files of the same package can use everything from the package without importing it and without using the package name (doesn't matter in which file it is defined). This is also true for unexported identifiers. From an another package you can only access exported identifiers (their name must start with a capital letter).

Comment: But in my case server.go and config/routes.go are parts of same package

Comment: @Avdept The `main` package is special. Files which are marked to be part of package `main` will be compiled into executable binaries. If files are in _different_ folders, they will end up in different executable files, not the same. If the package is not the special `main`, then if files are not in the same folder, they are **not** part of the same package. The package is not just the last folder name, it is the full name starting from the source folder (which is excluded).

Comment: check ps in my question please

Comment: @Avdept If you move both files into the same folder, you have to pass both files to `go run` e.g. `go run server.go routes.go`.